# Adding an img to a div tag

Tags: css, image, html

I realise this problem may have been touched on before but here goes.

I have coded the top banner of a page that I am working on.

I am now required to add an image underneath that will have text sitting on top of it along with a form field and button.

This ideally needs to be situated within a div tag. This won't work however, no matter how hard I try it is unresponsive to my coding. Every time I try to place a background-image in the div wrapping the center content it just plain wont show.

Due to this I have ended up placing the image inside of the div as a normal image and having my text and form fields positioned absolute.

This seemed to work fine and nearing the end of the project I decided to check it out on firefox and a few different resolutions.

This resulted in my form fields and content within that section shifting to the right!

Can anybody help me here?

Really am stuck for a way to sort this.

You can find my code at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JpLkE

Comment: Can you explain a little more what happens when you try to put background image?

Comment: your question is not clear my friend. you are telling "my form fields and content within that section shifting to the right!". because you are given left: 1100px; for the formfields div. if you reduce then it will come left.

Comment: digvi - When I try to add a background image to that div it's almost like it doesnt register, adding a width and height value doesn't work either. I have even tried copying parts of my code that show on the bottom of the page and the top (the nav and "footer"). And they don't show in that position either, even if I set the divs position to absolute and try to force it to show it just wont.

Comment: naresh - My form fields and content have that value as it is the only way they will position themselves in the correct place for my monitor resolution. If they have smaller values they sit on the left of the page and show normally in lower resolutions. I need to add an image to the div that wraps these so that I can display text above it without the need to position absolute. Then I can use margins etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked, as per my understand, 
your first problem is- background image in not coming in within the , so put width and height inside  so look like

```
<img src="your_background_image.gif" alt="" height="42" width="42">
```

second is nav and footer is not coming in there place ....
put there  outside all  and fix the position in css.